# can two devices communicate without physical layer?

Tags: mac-address, layer1, ppp

can 2 device communicate with each other without data going to physical layer?
for example we just use protocol of data link layer that use MAC address , but transferring this frame data between 2 device look like transferring data in my pc , I mean communicate happen between 2 device with PPP but it dose not go to physical (like ethernet or wifi ,....) it just use data link layer like the data is transferring in one computer ?
I mean is there any topology in networking that it simulate data transfer between for example ram or hard but it really is transferring between 2 computer , and use mac address .

in summery can we communicate with just PPP and not going to physical layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can 2 device communicate with each other without data going to physical layer?

No. The physical layer is the one actually doing the bit lifting. Without physically transporting the data to another location there's no communication.

You're forgetting that the data link layer 'only' controls the flow of packets over a local network. Still, the packets need to move, across the physical-layer connections. PPP also requires a physical layer for actual communication - that may just be a simple serial line though, something connecting the two interfaces running PPP. (The interfaces themselves are also part of the physical layer, of course.)

If you *simulate* a network you don't need to have a real physical layer. (Apart from the fact that the memory bus of a computer also requires a physical layer...)

For a simple analogy, if you want to talk to another person you require vocal cords, ears and some air in between. Using sign language, you still require hands, eyes, and electromagnetic waves running in between.